# How to deploy react js single page application (SPA)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, react-router, react-redux

I use react router make single page application, and I try to build it with `npm run build` then I upload build folder to my web-server but my website just shows background. I want to know how to make it work.

2017-04-26T19:06:27.864737+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't

available, you can get their info via:

2017-04-26T19:06:27.864910+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm owner ls notes-
app-client

2017-04-26T19:06:27.865077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely 
additional logging output above.

2017-04-26T19:06:27.870949+00:00 app[web.1]:

2017-04-26T19:06:27.871279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the

following file with any support request:

2017-04-26T19:06:27.871450+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! /app/npm-debug.log

2017-04-26T19:06:27.993054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to

crashed 2017-04-26T19:06:42.961236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App

crashed" method=GET path="/" host=educationapp.herokuapp.com

request_id=72015192-8122-4fba-beb0-69c8f1e38129 fwd="49.228.99.168" dyno=

connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-04-26T19:06:43.534651+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App

crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=educationapp.herokuapp.com

request_id=83684431-92be-4080-a2f8-7165e21f6c72 fwd="49.228.99.168" dyno=

connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-04-26T19:14:57.478915+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App

crashed" method=GET path="/" host=educationapp.herokuapp.com

request_id=022a219d-2299-4d23-b713-6bb75497f0e6 fwd="49.228.99.168" dyno=

connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-04-26T19:14:57.922975+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App

crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=educationapp.herokuapp.com

request_id=ae9bf961-22a9-47f8-be5d-234d97f83ca3 fwd="49.228.99.168" dyno=

connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: where do you want to deploy your website? Are you trying heroku, aws, or openshift, etc ?

Comment: Did you see some JavaScript errors (F12 tools)?

Comment: @Jeroen Heier I just see "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

Comment: @GauravPaliwal heroku.And I want to know I can upload build folder to my shared server?.

Comment: can you please attach the logs and the process you used?

Comment: @Gaurav Paliwal I should try Isomorphic Method? .

Answer (score 1):

Heroku don't have official deployment buildpack for React apps. So you have to use `create-react-app-buildpack` by [Mars Hall](https://github.com/mars).

Here is the [link](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) to get this.

Please follow this documentation. It will help you if you have started your development using `create-react-app`.

Comment: thank you for your reply,I will follow your instruction.